# make a linear performing recursive palindrome function

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome, linear-programming

So I have to build a function that checks if something is a palindrome, but it has to be recursive and it has to be linear and it has to ignore punctuations. I can't use any imports and my teacher told me that using the translation function isn't efficient enough. I'm trying to re-engineer it but iI'm very much stumped.

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    newWrd = word.translate(None, "., ").lower()
    if  len(newWrd) <= 1:
        return True
    elif  newWrd[0] !=  newWrd [-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return isPalindrome(newWrd[1:-1])
```

Comment: so what do you think `word.translate` does algorithmically? Give us some pseudocode and perhaps we can help you get there.

Comment: @ShawnMehan i dont understand what you're asking me for. Algorithmically i think its a linear ((O) n) performing method since its only doing one thing but I cant help if my teach calls it inefficient.

Comment: *"i think its a linear ((O) n) performing method since its only doing one thing"* - you should probably read up a bit more on complexity analysis

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay thats probably true, but im in a class thats helping me learn something i am struggling with, but right now this is bothering me.

Comment: And complexity analysis is telling you about worst case performance. I wanted you to tell us what was happening in your `def` so that you would realize what you needed to do to remove the dependency on `translate`.

Comment: @ShawnMehan okay thank you :), this is what its doing

Comment: @ShawnMehan
def isplaindrome (enter word)
 newWrd = user input . take out all commas periods and spaces. lower case all letters
if the lenth of newWrd is  less than or equal to 1 then 
 
return true 
else if the first letter in newWrd is not equal to the last letter then
 return false
else
call ispalindrome and check the 2nd and 2nd to last letter.

Answer (score 1):

The concept and motivation are simple:

- Check the first and last character of the current string.

  - If they match, repeat the previous operation, but only take the slice of the string that you *haven't* processed yet.
  - If they don't match, return `False`.
- Strings of length 1 are palindromic by default.

Here's what I would come up with.  The below assumes a unified case and that all punctuation is stripped out of the word, but if you wish to do that in this method, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

```
def palindrome(word):
    if not word:
        return False
    if len(word) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return palindrome(word[1:-1])
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should import `string` and use `string.punctuation`, but since you don't want to import anything, you can just hard-copy it to your code.

Since you already have the `isPalindrome()` recursive function, you can write a `wrapper` function, `isPalindromeWrapper()`, which will take the input, process it (remove the punctuations) and then call the `isPalindrome()` function.

```
punctuations = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

def removePunctuations(word):
    return ''.join( [ c for c in word if c not in punctuations ] )

def isPalindrome(word):
    print('isPalindrome({}) called.'.format(word))
    if len(word) < 2:
        return True
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        return isPalindrome(word[1:-1])
    return False

def isPalindromeWrapper(word):
    word = removePunctuations(word)
    return isPalindrome(word)

print isPalindromeWrapper('ab,c!b?a')
```

### Output:

```
isPalindrome(abcba) called.
isPalindrome(bcb) called.
isPalindrome(c) called.
True
```

Comment: boo. an answer, yes, but not a stronger programmer because of it :(

Comment: @Sait I came up with the exact same solution but had to refrain from posting it. Nice exercise, though! :-)

Comment: @Sait now it has to ignore punctuations and spaces